# Location Background Service that never closes

Tags: java, android, android-location

I am creating an application for device tracking for my company (own company devices)

I created a Background Service using the `GooglePlay API` to get the updates.

However, when my application is closed, it rarely sends the locations to the server. Rarely does it get update updates.

What should I do? Is there any special permission I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for this purpose. Even if your app is being killed process scheduled in WorkManager will be executed.

In your case, you can schedule to check location at a fixed interval and send it to server or wherever you want to send.

**From official doc:**

> The WorkManager API makes it easy to specify deferrable, asynchronous
>   tasks and when they should run. These APIs let you create a task and
>   hand it off to WorkManager to run immediately or at an appropriate
>   time. For example, an app might need to download new resources from
>   the network from time to time. Using these classes, you can set up a
>   task, choose appropriate circumstances for it to run (like "only while
>   device is charging and online"), and hand it off to WorkManager to run
>   when the conditions are met. **The task is still guaranteed to run, even
>   if your app is force-quit or the device is rebooted.**

Your task will come under [Recurring tasks](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#recurring)